# Print a list from another function

Tags: python, list, function

How can I get this to work
Should I use a gloabl variable or a args?
I'm very confused.

```
def getvenueurl():
    # code as part of a loop
    venueURList.append(tMD)
    # end loop


def getraceurl():
    print(venueURList)


getvenueurl()
getraceurl()
```

Comment: You should avoid global variables whenever possible. They are an indication for badly structured code, but there are very few exceptions to this general rule of thumb (your use case is _not_). To suit you needs, you should just pass a variable to each function, return the changed variable and pass your information around that way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case you can define the variable outside of functions scope.
Exemple:

```py
venueURList = []

def getvenueurl():
    # code as part of a loop
    venueURList.append(tMD)
    # end loop


def getraceurl():
    print(venueURList)


getvenueurl()
getraceurl()
```

Comment: This worked, thanks matie!
Even tho its the less prefer way as its a global its fine.
I was trying to add Globlal venueURList as lots of other post said that, but I think thats the version before Python 3.

Comment: You're welcome! If your problem has been solved, mark my answer as correct so that I can gain a reputation

Comment: @MightyDucks globals work in both new and old versions of Python.  The reason to avoid them is that it makes it impossible to follow the variable flow throughout a program.  I once worked on a C program that used globals instead of parameters, and it was impossible to work with - I hated it.

Answer (score 0):

In order to access a global variable inside a function, you must type:

```
global venueURList
```

before it is referenced or modified (in your case, append and print)

Generally, it is a better idea to pass the global variable into the parameter and return it instead.

```
def getvenueurl(venueList):
    venueList.append(tMD)
    return venueList
```

Comment: Defining a `global` variable is not needed to solve the OP's problem and is very often being considered as a bad practise.

Comment: That's true. I have added another solution.

Comment: How do you you print this @Fester

Comment: @MightyDucks you can easily print by putting the function into print(): `print(getvenueurl(venueURList))`

Answer (score 0):

Just return the list in a function. Store the returned value in a variable and pass it through a new function.

```
def getvenueurl():
    # code as part of a loop
    venueURList.append(tMD)
    return venueURList
    # end loop


def getraceurl(lst):
    print(lst)


venueList = getvenueurl()
getraceurl(venueList)
```

Or another option would be to use `global venueURList`